# AlertDialog NullPointerException in Android source code

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, android-alertdialog, weak-references

A user reported a `NullPointerException` happening on the line of `onClick` of my AlertDialog:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(getString(R.string.dialog_error))
        .setMessage(getString(R.string.create_failed_error))
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.dialog_got_it), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  // #L286
                dialog.cancel();
                mButton.render();
            }
        })
        .create().show();
```

The error is thus rooted in the `android.internal.app.AlertController` on [Line 160](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/app/AlertController.java#L160):

```
((DialogInterface.OnClickListener) msg.obj).onClick(mDialog.get(), msg.what);
```

From what I can guess `mDialog` is null here, but how can this happen? From the implementation we learn the dialog is stored in a weak reference:

```
private WeakReference<DialogInterface> mDialog;
```

Is it maybe possible that the dialog gets garbage collected before the user presses on the positive dialog button? I find this highly confusing

StackTrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.myapp.android.NewActivity$5.onClick(NewActivity.java:286)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Button gets instantiate in `onCreate`

```
mButton = new CustomButton((CustomButton) findViewById(R.id.goButton));
```

Comment: `mButton.render();`. mButton will be null. Remove all statements in onClick to see.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя It's a end-user crash report, I am not able to reproduce this crash locally.

@greenapps No, the crash happens on the line of `onClick` `com.myapp.android.activities.NewActivity$5.onClick(NewActivity.java:286)`

Comment: what is line number 286 in your NewActivity ?

Comment: If it is an end user complain then how do you know which line?

Comment: @user2450263 That line is `public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {`

Comment: @greenapps When a user sends a crash report from their phone, Google Developer console displays you the stack trace

Comment: @greenapps - I'm sure he has the stack trace.  But Mahoni is stubbornly refusing to show it to us.  Or the other stuff that would allow us to help him  Meh.  Moving on to a more interesting question.

Comment: Just change the code to `if ( mButton==null) { toast your button is null } else mButton.render();` And send him an update.

Comment: @StephenC Posted the stacktrace
greenapps: your fix won't help here. It's not where the Exception is raised.

Comment: the only thing that is possible is that mButton is null. So please also show us where You have initialized the button and where You open the dialog..

Comment: @Opiatefuchs in `onCreate`

Comment: What do you expect the line `dialog.cancel()` to do? Cancel the dialog? But the `dialog` variable is null right now, no? Where do you assign the dialog variable anyway?

Comment: The dialog object is not null, it´s part of the parameters from onClick: onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not a copy/paste issue, You problem must be here:

```
     mButton = new CustomButton((CustomButton) findViewById(R.id.goButton));
```

That´s a wrong coding, neither it has to be:

```
     mButton = new CustomButton(this);
```

Where this stands for context, or possible without parameter. or it has to be like this:

```
    mButton = (CustomButton)findViewById(R.id.goButton);
```

Don´t know if this is what the only problem is, but I have to show the code, bad to do it as a comment.